# Angular + Nodejs Express: ERROR Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, cross-domain

I'm trying to post data from angular (on port 4200) to the back-end node.js express server on port 3000.

**What I've done so far:** I have tried to post the json data from angular to the httpbin.org (a 3rd party server for test use), which proves that my function in angular is valid to post the json data.

Also, I used angular to get data from API of other websites, and they all work, only the nodejs server which is hosted on port 3000 has CORS problem when posting data from angular to it.

I have been googling to change the header of cors for the nodejs server and checked the firewall and lots of other approaches, but nothing works, I always get the CORS error.

```
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**

**ERROR:**
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
​
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData: 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
​
url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

**the Angular file: compoent.ts**

```
getData(loc : any) {
  
    //angular --> nodejs
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post<any>("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData", JSON.stringify(loc)).subscribe(response =>{
      console.log(response);
    });
```

**I tried all kinds of headers and cors that I can find on the internet in this Nodejs file but nothing works: app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const cors = require('cors')
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes 
//app.use(cors())

const corsOpts = {
    origin: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  
    methods: [
      'GET',
      'POST',
    ],
  
    allowedHeaders: [
      'Content-Type',
    ],
  };
  
  app.use(cors(corsOpts));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // next();
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '127.0.0.1:3000');
    

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
    });

app.use(
    cors({
      allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"], // you can change the headers
      exposedHeaders: ["authorization"], // you can change the headers
      origin: "*",
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      preflightContinue: false
    })
  );

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("wtffffffffffffffffff");//send to the page
})

app.get('/getAPIResponse', (req, res, next) => {
    api_helper.make_API_call('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => {
        res.json(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })
})

//angular --> nodejs
app.post('/api/postData',cors(), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("/postData success when running ng serve");
    console.log(req.body);    
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`NodeJS App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**This is the proxy file : proxy.conf.json**

```
    {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
      "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
      "secure" : false,
      "changeOrigin" : true
    }
  }
```

Comment: You seem to have your origins incorrect in multiple places on the node side. The origin url should be your angular url (http://localhost:4200) not your api url like you have now.

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks for reply but I don't get your words, the post method is at the last part of the app.js file, do you mean that I should change this method "app.post('/api/postData',cors(), (req, res, next){}"? and how should I change it? The two app.get() is for my node.js test use to make sure my nodejs works fine

Comment: Its you cors config and other headers there. Like corsOpts = {
    origin: '127.0.0.1:3000' and res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '127.0.0.1:3000'); those are both incorrect.

Comment: @MikeOne  I changed them to 4200 but still the same problem.

Comment: You are essentially mixing up 2 different approaches. CORS is one solution. Using proxy config is another. Do one or the other, not both!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple: I did not run the nodejs server at the backend

Comment: you need to configure the Node backend to allow requests from other origins. 
look at the docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: You need to configure the Node backend to allow requests from other origins. 
look at the docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests)

Simple Usage (Enable All CORS Requests)

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Get the basic CORS setup working first and then think about battoning down the hatches with some CORS config.

Also remove your proxy config if you are using CORS. Make HTTP requests direct from FE (browser) to your BE server if using CORS.

Comment: I tried this and removed the proxy file, but it does not work, still CORS error, Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postData: 0 Unknown Error",  why is this unknown error, is it even because of the cors ?

Comment: doesnt sound like it - try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1? if that dont work then add express 404 handler and 500 error handler - see if its even hitting your server - also always return res.json({some:'json'}) when using app.get app.post etc

Comment: Can nodejs be accessed from browser when the angular is running? I tried to run nodejs in cmd but failed when the angular is running, is this the reason?

Comment: yah u need to run both Angular and node server at same time - use 2 different terminal windows for this